# Magento admin form search/reset filter redirects to dashboard

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, magento-1.5

In a large number of our grid forms in our current Magento backend clicking the "Search" or "Reset Filter" buttons will redirect to the admin user start page. This happens in related products, sales orders and any of those style of forms except for the products list in Catalog >> Manage Products

Comment: I can provide log in details if it's easier to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser it happens in? If it has happened in IE9 then you could upgrade JS Prototype framework, which Magento used, at least to 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
public function gridAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

to your controller